# is it possible to call a web service from cooja?

Tags: python, web-services, serial-communication, cooja, contiki-ng

is it possible to call a web service from cooja? May be I can read from border-router then call web service (via python script for example). I can ping border-router but I dont know how to read from node or write to node in cooja.I am new to contiki-ng and cooja. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the websense example at the folder **~/contiki/examples/ipv6/sky-websense**